# Какой выбрать ресурс для распознавания намерения для чат бота?

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, nlp

Имеется необходимость написать чат бота, используя `node.js`. На этапе обсуждения встал вопрос - чем пользоваться для распознавания намерения, тем более русского? 
Входные данные следующие: чат бот будет связан с медициной, и находится будет на локальном сервере, как следствие - облачные варианты типа [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) не подходят. Нужно что-то, что можно установить на сервер. Подскажите пожалуйста, чем можно воспользоваться.